# Advanced Json object handling in PHP

Tags: php, json, object, decode, encode

I'm trying to send some Json data to my server side PHP code, but i got an error message:

> Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\registration.php on line xy.

Here is my Json object. what I want to handle:

```
   registrationInputData:{"page1":{"regfnev":"John","reglnev":"Kerry","regemail":"john.kerry@gmail.com","regpassword":"Qwerty01"},"page2":{"regtelepules":"Budapest","regirsz":"1123","regutca":"","reghazszam":"","regemelet":"","regajto":"","regtelszam":""},"page3":{"regprofilimage":"dogProfileImage","regfeltetel":true}}
```

And here is my PHP:

```
<?php
session_start();
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "getpet");
mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");
$result = false;

if(isset($_POST['registrationInputData'])){
$registrationInputData = json_encode($_POST['registrationInputData']);

///page1
$fname = $registrationInputData->page1->regfnev;
$lname = $registrationInputData->page1->reglnev;
$email = $registrationInputData->page1->regemail;
$password = md5($registrationInputData->page1->regpassword);

$emailquery = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = '".$email."'";
$emailsql = mysqli_query($conn, $emailquery);
if(mysqli_num_rows($emailsql) == "0"){

    ///page2
    $settlement = $registrationInputData->page2->regtelepules;
    $postcode = $registrationInputData->page2->regirsz;
    $street = $registrationInputData->page2->regutca;
    $streetnumber = $registrationInputData->page2->regutca;
    $floor = $registrationInputData->page2->regemelet;
    $door = $registrationInputData->page2->regajto;
    $phone = $registrationInputData->page2->regtelszam;

    ///page3
    $profilimage = $registrationInputData->page3->regprofilimage;
    $conditionaccepted = $registrationInputData->page3->regfeltetel;

    $registrationquery =
    "INSERT INTO users (fname, lname, email, password, settlement, postcode, street, streetnumber, floor, door, phone, profilimage, conditionaccepted)
     VALUES ('".$fname."', '".$lname."', '".$email."', '".$password."', '".$settlement."', '".$postcode."', '".$street."', '".$streetnumber."', '".$floor."', '".$door."', '".$phone."', '".$profilimage."', '".$conditionaccepted."' )";
     $result = true;
}
}
echo $result;

?>
```

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: `json_encode` __encodes__ json. `json_decode` __decodes__.

Comment: oops. you are right

Comment: problem solved, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use json_decode function if it is json string you are getting in post. Then you can access the object elements.